# Can I avoid using `Theano.scan`?

Tags: theano

I have 3-dimensional tensor (`"tensor3"` -- an array of matrices), and I'd like to compute the determinant (`theano.sandbox.linalg.det`) of each matrix. Is there a way to compute each determinant without using `theano.scan`? When I try calling `det` directly on the tensor I get the error

```
3-dimensional array given. Array must be two-dimensional.
```

But I read that `scan` is slow and doesn't parallelize well, and that one should use only tensor operations if possible. Is that so? Can I avoid using scan in this case?

Comment: Have been looking for a better way to do this too. Any leads? 3 years later one would think there would be a simple way of performing common functions on tensors in Theano.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 possibilities:

- If you know before compiling the Theano function the number of matrix in the tensor3 variable, you could use the split() op or just call det() on all matrix in the tensor3.
- If you don't know the shape, you can make your own op, that will loop over the input and call the numpy fct. See for [an example](http://www.deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/extending_theano.html) on how to make an op.
- Use scan. It is easy to use it for this case. See [this example](https://github.com/nicholas-leonard/Theano/commit/74a6265f15ef332d98e3e55aef0bc3c979682269), just change the call from tensordot to det().